# Salesforce - commandButton issue when use reRender

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, commandbutton, rerender

I have a VisualForce for create Cases, this VisualForce is going to be embedded on a Site, so the VisualForce it is built on HTML and inside the HTML I put the following :

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" docType="" Controller="MyController">
<html>
    <body>
        <!--
            HTML PAGE
        -->
        <div id="FileUpload" class="row">
            <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FileUploadForm">
                <apex:pageMessages id="TheMessage" />
                <apex:pageBlock>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
                            <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!strFileName}" id="file"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!cargarArchivo}" value="Cargar Archivo" reRender="TheMessage"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

And the Controller is:

```
public String strFileName {get; set;}

public Document document {
    get {
        if (document == null)
            document = new Document();
        return document;
    }
    set;
}

public void cargarArchivo() {
    document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    document.FolderId = '00l29000000L2uH';
    document.name = strFileName;
    document.description = strFileName;
    document.keywords = strFileName;

    try {
        insert document;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error cargando el archivo, por favor intente nuevamente'));
        return;
    } finally {
        document.body = null; // clears the viewstate
        document = new Document();
    }

    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Archivo cargado con éxito.'));
}
```

Up to here everything works very well, but when y add the reRender to the commandButton, like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!cargarArchivo}" value="Cargar Archivo" reRender="TheMessage"/>
```

I get the following error:

```
3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript:178 
    Uncaught TypeError: actionUrl.indexOf is not a function
        at A4J.Query.getActionUrl (3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript:178)
        at A4J.AJAX.XMLHttpRequest.send (3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript:67)
        at Object.A4J.AJAX.SubmitQuery (3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript:125)
        at Object.A4J.AJAX.Submit (3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript:126)
        at HTMLInputElement.onclick (RF2_CrearCasoWeb_pag?negocio=WEB_GIE:559)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use re-render or you can use inputfile tag. They can not be used together, as the error states.

Your page messages re-rendered automatically without mentioned. So you don't worry about that.

As a best practice you can use iframe tag, which embeds an independent HTML document into the current document.